# Homeomorphism via Minkowski functional?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $E$ is an infinite dimensional topological vector space and $\Omega\subset E$ is open, convex and $0\in \Omega$.
The Minkowski-functional of $\Omega$ is defined by:
$$
p_\Omega:E\to \mathbb{R},\quad p_\Omega(v):=\inf\{\lambda>0\, |\, v\in \lambda \Omega\}.
$$
I would like to show that $\Omega$ is homeomorphic to $E$.
**Question:** Is the map
$$
\varphi:\Omega\to E, \quad \varphi(x):=\frac{x}{1-p_\Omega(x)}
$$
a homeomorphism from $\Omega$ to $E$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Since $p_\Omega$ is homogeneous of degree $1$, we have 
$$p_\Omega(\varphi(x))= \frac{p_{\Omega}(x)}{1-p_\Omega(x)} \tag1$$ Let $y=\varphi(x)$. Rearrange (1) into 
$$p_\Omega(x) = \frac{p_{\Omega}(y)}{1+p_\Omega(y)} \tag2$$  and conclude that 
$$\varphi^{-1}(y) = \frac{y}{1+p_\Omega(y)}\tag2$$
It remains to show that $p_\Omega$ is a continuous function on $E$. To this end, observe that for any positive number $t$ the sets $\{x:p_\Omega(x)<t\}=t\Omega$ and $\{x:p_\Omega(x)>t\}=E\setminus \overline{t\Omega}$ are open.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!